# what are my IIS Application Pool credentials?

Tags: c#, .net, security, iis

In IIS 7 my virtual directory is using an app pool with identiy ApplicationPoolIdentity

I need to add permission for this group to use aspnet_regiis to decrypt connectionStrings in a .NET application

What group is this? If instead of using ApplicationPoolIdentity I use NetworkService then I know this group is "NT Authority\Network service" and I can grant permission using :

```
aspnet_regiis -pa "RSAKeyName" "NT Authority\Network service"
```

What is the group name for ApplicationPoolIdentity?